ERROR: KTUsersAddUser.init is not a function
en la aplicacion Web que estoy trabajando sin venir a cuento cuando entro al apartado de usuarios e intento crear un nuevo usuario o editar uno existente a veces saltan los errores de las imágenes y no se realiza la acción de crear/modificar usuario incluso a veces salta el error en la consola solo con entrar a la pagina en cuestión.

He estado modificando la aplicación previamente pero solo temas estéticos y scripts que atacan a un elemento en especifico que acaba cuando ese elemento realiza X acción, es mas, desconocía la existencia de este archivo ya que la aplicación ya estaba hecha antes de yo añadir modificaciones.
Voy a adjuntar donde se referencia el archivo add.js que es el que ocasiona el error
Archivo Users.php (Es donde se visualizan en una tabla los ususarios y donde se crean/modifican/eliminan)
<!-- Aquí finaliza el HTML -->

<script src="assets/js/custom/apps/user-management/users/list/add.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom/apps/user-management/users/list/table.js"></script>

<!-- Aquí comienzan el rest de scripts generales e la pagina -->

Archivo add.js
"use strict";

var KTUsersAddUser = function () {
    const t = document.getElementById("kt_modal_add_user");
    const e = t.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_user_form");
    const n = new bootstrap.Modal(t);

    return {
        init: function () {
            (() => {
                var o = FormValidation.formValidation(e, {
                    fields: {
                        user_name: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Full name is required"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        user_email: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Valid email address is required"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        password: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Password is required'
                                },
                                stringLength: {
                                    min: 8,
                                    message: 'Password must be at least 8 characters long'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        password_confirm: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Password confirmation is required'
                                },
                                identical: {
                                    compare: function () {
                                        return e.querySelector('[name="password"]').value;
                                    },
                                    message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                        bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                            rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                            eleInvalidClass: "",
                            eleValidClass: ""
                        })
                    }
                });

                const i = t.querySelector('[data-kt-users-modal-action="submit"]');
                i.addEventListener("click", (t) => {
                    t.preventDefault();
                    o && o.validate().then((t) => {
                        console.log("validated!");
                        if ("Valid" == t) {
                            i.setAttribute("data-kt-indicator", "on");
                            i.disabled = !0;
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                i.removeAttribute("data-kt-indicator");
                                i.disabled = !1;
                                Swal.fire({
                                    text: "Form has been successfully submitted!",
                                    icon: "success",
                                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                                    confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                                    customClass: {
                                        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                                    }
                                }).then((t) => {
                                    t.isConfirmed && n.hide();
                                });
                            }, 2000);
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                                icon: "error",
                                buttonsStyling: !1,
                                confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                                customClass: {
                                    confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            })();

            t.querySelector('[data-kt-users-modal-action="cancel"]').addEventListener("click", (t) => {
                t.preventDefault();
                Swal.fire({
                    text: "Are you sure you would like to cancel?",
                    icon: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: !0,
                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, cancel it!",
                    cancelButtonText: "No, return",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                        cancelButton: "btn btn-active-light"
                    }
                }).then((t) => {
                    if (t.value) {
                        e.reset();
                        n.hide();
                    } else if ("cancel" === t.dismiss) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Your form has not been cancelled!",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            t.querySelector('[data-kt-users-modal-action="close"]').addEventListener("click", (t) => {
                t.preventDefault();
                Swal.fire({
                    text: "Are you sure you would like to cancel?",
                    icon: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: !0,
                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, cancel it!",
                    cancelButtonText: "No, return",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                        cancelButton: "btn btn-active-light"
                    }
                }).then((t) => {
                    if (t.value) {
                        e.reset();
                        n.hide();
                    } else if ("cancel" === t.dismiss) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Your form has not been cancelled!",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
};

KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(() => {
    KTUsersAddUser.init();
});


Si necesitan mas información o mas código no duden en pedirla.
Espero puedan ayudarme, ¡muchísimas gracias a todos!
